# Unable to install IIS - Application Development Features - ASP.NET

Tags: iis, iis-7

If I install IIS with Application Development Features - ASP.NET (or installing IIS first and adding ASP.NET later on). It's giving me the dreaded error:

**An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed.**

I tried uninstalling WAS. I uninstalled and reinstalled .NET 3.5.1.  I repaird .NET 4.0

If I install IIS without that feature, then it would let me.

Any suggestions?! Is this the correct place to ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

Try first removing all internet information services and world wide services and start all over with full options.